# How to call a Model Method from a Controller in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model, controller

In my model I have something like:

```
class CML < Lead
 def model_method
  #something
 end
end
```

and in my Controller:

```
def recommend
    @var.model_method
    #more stuff
  end
```

and @var is a CML object, however I keep getting:

> undefined method `model_method' for #

Does anyone knows why?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try removing @ and just `var.model_method`?

Comment: it doesn’t work neither @uDaY

Comment: `@var = CML.new` then `@var.model_method`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems @var is empty at that point

you should use something like (choose one):

```
@var = Var.find params[:id]
#or
@var = Var.new
#or
@var = Var.create
```

then you could call your

`@var.model_method`